# Help optimizing boot / slow boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 10. The boot up time for Ubuntu seems unnecessarily long. I had to add `rootdelay=75` so I don't end up at dropping to a shell.

From `dmesg` this seems to be where I am getting hung up:

```
[    4.692189] ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[    4.696195] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[    4.752326] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    4.848454] ata2.00: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 330)
[    4.849291] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da
[    4.849292] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    4.852501] ata2.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[    4.860703] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    4.862050] ata2.00: ATA-9: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB, EMT02B6Q, max UDMA/133
[    4.863384] ata2.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    4.872709] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    4.874618] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    4.960758] Switched to clocksource tsc
[    9.896689] ata1.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   13.371570] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   14.720707] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   19.921141] ata1.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   23.396097] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   24.745233] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   29.945669] ata1.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   58.473929] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   58.475323] ata1.00: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   58.476663] ata1.01: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   59.827069] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   63.514215] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   63.527069] ata1.00: reset failed, giving up
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'd first check for a Samsung firmware update for your SSD. Then I'd check for partition misalignment... for a quick check... do `sudo fdisk -l`. Ping me at `@heynnema` and report back.

Comment: Make sure to start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. fdisk looks ok. Check the Samsung firmware. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema
Samsung is limited in their support for Linux users. They do make a tool called "magician" for windows users, that includes a firmware updater. They also make one for Linux enterprise users but I can't seem to get the executable to run. [link] ( http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html)

Comment: @heynnema
`sudo fdisk -l         [ 1:08PM]


WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.



Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes

255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x08938b4c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
`

Comment: Use the Windows Magician.

Comment: Instead of fdisk, you can use `sudo parted -l` and `sudo parted align-check optimal partition_#`.

Comment: @heynnema
`Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  473MB   472MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag 2      473MB   578MB   105MB   fat32           EFI system partition boot
 3 578MB   595MB   16.8MB Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4 595MB   510GB   509GB   ntfs Basic data partition  msftdata
 5 510GB   983GB   473GB   ext4
 6 983GB   1000GB  17.1GB  linux-swap(v1)`

Comment: @heynnema, I should log into Windows and run Magician? The align-check gave me an error. `sudo parted align-check                                                             [ 1:30PM]
Error: Could not stat device align-check - No such file or directory.     
Retry/Cancel?`

Comment: Yes, log into Windows, download the Samsung Magician, and check your firmware. You didn't do the parted command correctly... you forgot the partition_# (shown by the first parted command that I show).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I recommend you try is make sure the UUID in `/etc/fstab` is correct. You can do this by running

```
blkid
```

then make sure the UUIDs it gives you match what is in `/etc/fstab`.
 If that fails to help, and you have a hard drive, try using something like e4rat or  [e4rat-lite](https://github.com/ShyPixie/e4rat-lite) . Keep in mind that both haven't been updated in a few years. They still work for me. It also appears that you have an old kernel version, try updating with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I'd also recommend updating to 16.04, or reinstalling your current version.

Comment: UUID looks correct. My hard drive is a solid state - do you think e4rat-lite would still help?

Comment: It won’t help with SSDs.

Comment: The use of blkid requires sudo... `sudo blkid`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error message on ata1 was referring to an actual hardware failure. Once I removed the hardware, a 25 GB SSD, I no longer get this error and boot speed is greatly improved. From 75-80 sec down to 8  sec (on the first reboot since removing the drive).